# WAB's AGOL search bar dropdown list No Results error

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

After following all the [steps](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-feature-search.htm) in Web Map > Settings > Application Settings > By Layer > Save.... the search bar's dropdown list returns the error message No Results

Have attempted multiple combinations is the Application Settings and it is still not working...

I found a [thread](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/agol-web-app-generates-quot-no-results-quot-error-when-clicking/m-p/612580#M30559) on the topic, but still looking for a solution.

Is this still a known issue?

We are using a Feature Service (not a Map Service) due to selection tolerance issues if that matters.

[image]

Comment: Try to check by removing string fields, also did you tried using a single field?

Comment: I tried using a single field, deleting everything / adding back, and few other combinations... it always reverts back to "No Results" issue in search bar... these field have to be string (text) considering the values in them.